# Find Plugin by file name

Tags: plugins

how can I figure out given a file name the plugin to which it belongs.

is there a tab or place where i can check ?

some are easy and can be seen by the directory, but other files have too generic names ?

I mean files that are red when the page loads, such as .js, .css
when you do speed tests.

F.e. .../jquery.js, ../style.css

---

Current files I cant figure out :

```
/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0
/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.3.2
```

Comment: what kind of filename and where are you getting the filename from?

Comment: Red where? In your browser console or network tab because they're missing? Your browser should be able to tell you the complete path it's trying to load. If you really can't get it from the browser you can also look for error responses in your web server's access log (anything that has HTTP code 400+ or 500+)

Comment: sorry if it wasnt clear, i have the full path and the name of the file, I'm looking for a general way to figure out to which plugin it belongs to. Say I go to Theme editor and chose a file, or in the browser Inspect/Networking and pick a file, or speed test like  DTMetrix ... any existing file i.e. reverse lookup path/file ==> Plugin

Comment: Can you give us an example then? Generally they're all obvious by directory: /wp-includes is from WordPress Core, /wp-content/themes/<name>/ is from the named theme, /wp-content/plugins/<name>/ is from the named plugin, and that's about all you'd expect to see.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: OK, jQuery is one of the trickier ones: it's provided by WordPress core but not included by default unless requested by one of your plugins or your theme. Search your plugin or theme files for a wp_enqueue_script line that mentions jquery, either explicitly as the script to include or as a dependency for another script enqueued. (Or just search them all for the word 'jquery')

Comment: It may also be possible to spot this by var_dump()ing the global $wp_scripts - if it's included as a dependency of another script you'll be able to see that there. You could also dump arguments and stack track for all wp_enqueue_script calls, either to the screen or to the error_log.

Comment: That said there shouldn't really be any reason jQuery is a problem. What's it red for: load time, or script run time, or something else?

Comment: thanks, it is not a problem. i'm trying to optimize load times by postponing some .js and .css. My logic is if it is not part of the  theme, I can postpone, otherwise not (with Flying scripts plugin)